# Swedish permenant residency

Tags: sweden, residency

I worked in Sweden as a work permit holder for 1 year and 3 months before I moved to USA. If I move back to Sweden after 1 year will my previous 1 year and 3 months work permit count towards getting a PR?

Comment: This should be asked on Expatriates SE, I think, not on Law SE.